# Send animation file with Telegram api

Tags: c#, telegram, telegram-bot

I have a animation file (*.tgs) in project directory.

I want to send it with telegram api, I use this code but when I sent a file, it didn't show animation.

```
 var path = HostingEnvironment.MapPath("/Content/Sticker/0.tgs" );
 using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
   {
     var destStream = fs;
     destStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
     InputOnlineFile fileToSend = new InputOnlineFile(fs,"cd");

     await botApi.SendAnimationAsync(channelId, fileToSend);
    }
```

When I use (*.webp) file, it is ok and sends a sticker.

Comment: Reading this : https://core.telegram.org/stickers it looks like the tgs way is a bit different to use than other sticker (I just looked quickly, might be wrong). When searching the github page of telegram-bot, I get these : https://github.com/TelegramBots/Telegram.Bot/search?q=tgs . Could be wirth exploring those different functions?

Comment: Also, what is the size of your particular .tgs file ?